# Positioning of a variable number of spans inside div

Tags: html, css

this might be a super-trivial answer but i cannot seem to get my head around it.

I have a div object, which contains up to n span elements (the number is variable and can be between 1 and e.g. 3). I would like the spans to be positioned on the bottom left corner of the left-floated div (part1). The spans should stack horizontally, with variable width.

```
<div class="card">
 <span class="meta-data">
    <span class="tag">Something </span>
    <span class="tag">Something else </span>
    <span class="tag">Something else else</span>    
 </span>  
 <div class="part1"></div>
<div class="part2"></div>
```

Here is a js Fiddle with simple example code (please note that the positioning in this is jot correct.): http://jsfiddle.net/fritschs/h5n04gzo/

I was thinking of using the n-th children selector in css and position absolute every span, however, how would i approach this with a variable number of spans?

Thanks for any input

Comment: stack horizontally? or stack vertically?

Comment: You want the tags to be positioned relative to div.part1 and not their parent? It would be easier if the spans were inside the div.part1

Comment: Sorry meant stack vertically :)

Comment: I think you want to do [this](http://jsfiddle.net/h5n04gzo/7/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fritschs/h5n04gzo/) again...
I just added this lines:

```
.card{position:relative;}
.card .meta-data{position:absolute; bottom:0; left:0;}
.card .meta-data span{ float:left; margin-right:10px;}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are 3 things to do here.

1. Set the card to `position:relative` so that you can control the absolute positioning of the `meta-data` - [see this page](http://css-tricks.com/absolute-positioning-inside-relative-positioning/).
2. Set the `meta-data` to `bottom:0` to move it to the bottom of the `card`.
3. Set the `tag` to `float:left;` to stack them horizontally. You could also add a `margin:right` to space them out a bit if you like.

```css
.card {
    width: 400px;
    height: 200px;
    position:relative;
}
.part1 {
    float:left;
    height: 100%;
    width: 50%;
    background-color: blue;    
}
.part2 {
    float:right;
    height: 100%;
    width: 50%;
    background-color:red;    
}

.meta-data {
    position: absolute;
    bottom:0;
}

.tag {
    display: block;
    float:left;
    margin-right:2px;
    background-color: grey;
    font-size: 0.625rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="card">
    <span class="meta-data">
        <span class="tag">Something </span>
        <span class="tag">Something else </span>
        <span class="tag">Something else else</span>    
    </span>    
    <div class="part1">
    </div>
    <div class="part2"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a mill. That works. One tiny question, why are the spans all the same width, see my updated js fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/fritschs/h5n04gzo/

Comment: That is because they are set set as `display:block` so they take up the full width of the parent (`meta-data`). And as `meta-data` is `position:absolute` its width is the same as it's widest child.